# How to highlight selected button in React?

Tags: reactjs

The following react component has four buttons, created using the data extracted from the props sent by the parent component. You can find the entire project here -> https://github.com/rajendrashenoy/myresume-react-app

The application can be accessed through -> https://rajendrashenoy.github.io/myresume-react-app/

When any button is clicked, it returns the id of the button clicked to the parent component. My question is, how can I highlight the clicked button?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ResumeTypes extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }   

  render() {


  return this.props.resumetypes.map((resumetype, selectedtype) => (
       <input type="button" style={{width: '25%', border: "none"}} id={resumetype.id} key={resumetype.id} value={ resumetype.type} onClick={this.props.selectedtype.bind(this, resumetype.id)}/>        

    ));

  }
}
```

Comment: Keep a new state such as "selectedButton" then set this state with clicked button's id. Now, Look for if a button's "id" is equal to the "selectedButton" state. If yes, highlight it with a conditional class.

Answer (score 3):

By highlight, I assume you wish to change the background-color of the button
So, onClick, you set the ID of the active tab to the state and in className, you add the active class conditionally.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ResumeTypes extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {activeButton:''}
    //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleActiveButton(id) =>{
  this.props.selectedtype.bind(this, id)
  this.setState({activeButton: id})
  }

  render() {
   return this.props.resumetypes.map((resumetype, selectedtype) => (
       <input type="button" 
          className={`base-class ${this.state.activeButton == resumetype.id? 'active-color:'''}` } 
          style={{width: '25%', border: "none"}} 
          id={resumetype.id} 
          key={resumetype.id} 
          value={ resumetype.type} 
          onClick={(resumetype.id)=>handleActiveButton(resumetype.id)}
        />        
   ));
  }
}
```

In Style.css

```
.base-class{
     //your default button styling
}
.active-color{
      //your active button styling
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked with a minor change. this.props.selectedtype.bind(this, id)()

Answer (score 1):

You should store your currently selected button in your state.
Refresh the state value with your button ID every time one of them is clicked.

And then adapt the class of your button in your render function depending on whether or not it correspond with the selected value in the state :

```js
class ResumeTypes extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            selectedButton: null
        }
    }

    buttonSelected = selectedButton => ev => {
        this.setState({ selectedButton })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {['A', 'B', 'C'].map(key => 
                    <button className={key === this.state.selectedButton ? 'selected' : ''} type="button" style={{ width: '25%', border: "none" }} key={key} onClick={this.buttonSelected(key)}>{key}</button>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ResumeTypes />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.selected {
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Now just add the CSS of your choice to the button

Answer (score 1):

**May be this solution below can help you for your problem. You need an active state for this issue**

```js
const {useState,Fragment} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("");
 
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setActive(event.target.id);
    
  }

    return (
      <Fragment>
      <button
        key={1}
        className={active === "1" ? "active" : undefined}
        id={"1"}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Solution
      </button>

       <button
       key={2}
       className={active === "2" ? "active" : undefined}
       id={"2"}
       onClick={handleClick}
     >
      By
     </button>

      <button
      key={3}
      className={active === "3" ? "active" : undefined}
      id={"3"}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
        Jamal
    </button>
</Fragment>

    );
}


 ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.active{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The code your suggested worked, only had add a litte ()

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ResumeTypes extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {ClickedButton: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  } 

  handleChange(id) {

    this.setState({ClickedButton: id})
    this.props.selectedtype.bind(this, id)()

  }

  render() {


  return this.props.resumetypes.map((resumetype, selectedtype) => (
       <input type="button" 
       className={resumetype.id === this.state.ClickedButton ? "App-Button-Active" : "App-Button-Default"}
       style={{width: '25%', border: "none"}} 
       id={resumetype.id} 
       key={resumetype.id} 
       value={ resumetype.type} 
       onClick={ () => this.handleChange(resumetype.id)}/>
       //onClick={this.props.selectedtype.bind(this, resumetype.id)}/>      

    ));

  }
}

export default ResumeTypes;
```