# How to set CSS in the dynamically add button in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is my React class component for the simple survey form:-

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import "./SurveyFrom.css";

export class SurveyForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isSelected: false,
    selectedVal: 0,
  };
}

onHandleOnClick(data, e) {
  console.log(data);
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    isSelected: !prevState.isSelected,
  }));

  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    selectedVal: (prevState.selectedVal = data),
  }));
}

renderRating() {
  var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  return arr.map((val) => {
    return (
      <button
        className="q-range-item-button"
        onClick={(e) => this.onHandleOnClick(val, e)}
      >
        {val}
      </button>
    );
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="form">
        <label class="q-field-label" for="nps" title="Field is required">
          <div>
            {this.props.title}
            <span class="q-field-label-required">*</span>
          </div>
          <div></div>
        </label>
        <div>{this.renderRating()}</div>
        <div className="q-range-labels-text">
          <dive className="q-range-labels-text-max">
            Very likely&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </dive>
          <dive className="q-range-labels-text-min">Very unlikely</dive>
        </div>
        <div className="survey-form-submit">
          <button className="survey-form-submit-button" type="submit">
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default SurveyForm;
```

I want to apply some css style the button 0 to 10 when it is clicked.
Since I added 0 to 10 button added a by loop, I don't know how can I apply css styling to make selected button green. Can you suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello :) Similar topic is here. Take a look because You can find useful hints there 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310548/how-to-highlight-selected-button-in-react/54310960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I've refactored your code a little as well with some explanatory comments. I hope this is useful for you:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./SurveyFrom.css";

// This can be declared once outide the class, as it will never change
// Changed name to `ratings`, which is more expressive than `arr`
const ratings = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

export class SurveyForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // super(props); --> this is deprecated. You probably don't need it unless you're using an old version of React.
    // you could even get rid of the constructor entirely if you want
    this.state = {
      selectedRatingIndex: -1 // you only need one value to hold the selected state. Default to -1 to indicate none selected.
    };
  }

  renderRating = () =>
    // arrow function ensures correct binding to `this` SurveyForm instance
    ratings.map((val, index) => (
      <button
        key={val} // always add a unique key to your list items
        className={
          // this is where you will check if the selected rating is the current one, and switch the css class accordingly
          // here I've changed the class entirly, but you may just wish to add an additional class. Either way you'll do it here.
          this.state.selectedRatingIndex === index
            ? "MY_SELECTED_CSS_CLASS" // <-- change this name to whatever you want. Just make a class that adds `background: green;` or whatever you want
            : "q-range-item-button"
        }
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          // you can just inline this function. It's more readable and the performance loss is negligible
          console.log(val);
          this.setState({ selectedRatingIndex: index });
        }}
      >
        {val}
      </button>
    ));

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form">
          <label class="q-field-label" for="nps" title="Field is required">
            <div>
              {this.props.title}
              <span class="q-field-label-required">*</span>
            </div>
          </label>
          <div>{this.renderRating()}</div>
          <div className="q-range-labels-text">
            <dive className="q-range-labels-text-max">
              Very likely&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </dive>
            <dive className="q-range-labels-text-min">Very unlikely</dive>
          </div>
          <div className="survey-form-submit">
            <button className="survey-form-submit-button" type="submit">
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if some how I can prevent not to render anymore after the rating selection it should fulfills my requirements. I tried this:- `  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.isSelected) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }` It doens't work

Comment: yes, i fixed it in my code. But still the behavior is as shown in the video clip. How to prevent rendering to fix the applied css.

Comment: I debug and `console.log("selectedRatingIndex: " + this.state.selectedRatingIndex); `  output is selectedRatingIndex: -1. So setSate is not setting new sate for selectedRatingIndex

Comment: After setting the val to selectedRatingIndex.  selectedRatingIndex has updated value. Since it render is called and setting of css doesn't help.

Comment: yes this fixed the issue. It is working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to keep the button's value in the state. If the value or id of the button is the same as the value kept in the state than conditionally apply the class in the component. That class would style the button based on the specified rules.

State of Your component will be modified using the `onClick` handler on the button

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare the number in the render cycle:

```
    return (
      <button
        className=`q-range-item-button {$this.state.selectedVal === val ? 'rangebuttonenabled': ''}`
        onClick={(e) => this.onHandleOnClick(val, e)}
      >
        {val}
      </button>
    );
```

You just simply compare the number you stored on click, to the one you're trying to render adding a CSS class if this holds true.

You do need a CSS class for this: `.rangebuttonenabled {background-color: 'hotpink'}`, or just apply this logic as you see fit.